# Odoo 12 domain filter for stock.moves.line in multi company

Tags: odoo, inventory-management

I've a problem in filtering the movements of products in odoo. 
I've a structured hierarchy of company: a mother company, 6 child companies, and every child company has several childs companies. Every company has his set of user.
The catalog of product is shared for all the companies. When I try to get the report of a product movements the system will give me EVERY movements, even of the other companies.
I've tried to filter the results in **"stock.move.line.search"** with domain like:

```
domain="[('product_id.company_id','=',self.env.user.company_id)]"
```

And every variant I can imagine.
The main goal is to get only the movements of the active company for the user.
Where I'm doing wrong?

EDIT: 
I get the movement lines from Inventory->Master Data->Products->[I choose a product]->Product Moves. Here I've a list of ALL movement for that product, even for the other companies.
Filtering the by picking_type can "resolve" my problem:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<search string="Stock Moves">
            <field name="picking_id" string="Reference"/>
            <field name="product_id"/>
            <field name="location_id"/>
            <field name="location_dest_id"/>
            <separator/>
            <filter string="To Do" name="todo" domain="[('state','not in', ['done', 'draft'])]"/>
            <filter string="Done" name="done" domain="[('state','=','done')]"/>
            <separator/>
            <filter string="Receptions" name="incoming" domain="[('picking_id.picking_type_id.code','=','incoming')]"/>
            <filter string="Deliveries" name="outgoing" domain="[('picking_id.picking_type_id.code','=','outgoing')]"/>
            <filter string="Internal" name="internal" domain="[('picking_id.picking_type_id.code','=','internal')]"/>
            <filter string="Manufacturing" name="manufacturing" domain="[('picking_id.picking_type_id.code','=','mrp_operation')]"/>

            <separator/>
            <group expand="0" string="Group By">
                <filter string="Status" name="by_state" domain="[]" context="{'group_by':'state'}"/>
                **<filter string="Product" name="groupby_product_id" domain="[('picking_id.picking_type_id.code','=','internal')]" context="{'group_by': 'product_id'}"/>**
            </group>
        </search>
```

But the final user can remove the filter manually. How can I get an invariable result?

Comment: It depends on how you get the report of product movements, It will be very helpful to answer your question if you provide that

Comment: @Kenly From Inventory-Master Data-Products-[I choose a product]-Product Moves. Here I've a list of ALL movement for that product, even for the other companies.